# How to change text of label in a screen when I press a button in another screen in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, label, kivy

I am new to Kivy, so I have a question that I want to develop two screen in Kivy, the first one is about entering user details and passwords (no authentication, at this moment) and then second screen displays the user name (entered at the previous screen) and displays user name along with other widgets.
The basic idea is to get the value of a user form userlogin screen and display it to another screen.
Here is my code,

from kivy.app import App

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty # @UnresolvedImport


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    text = StringProperty()
    def change_text(self): 
        self.text = ''
        self.manager.current = 'StocksGUIScreen'

class StocksGUIScreen(Screen):
    label_text = StringProperty('')
    #pass


class PortfolioUIApp(App):
    #user_name = StringProperty()
    pass

PortfolioUIApp().run()
```

Here is my .kv file:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    LoginScreen:
        id: login_screen
        name: 'LoginScreen'
        manager: screen_manager
    StocksGUIScreen:
        id: stocks_gui
        name: 'StocksGUIScreen'
        manager: screen_manager
        label_text: login_screen.text


<LoginScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "User Name"
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
                #pos: root.x, root.top-self.height
                color: 0,1,0,1

            TextInput:
                id: user_name
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
                #on_text: root.user_name

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Password"
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            TextInput:
                id: pass_word
                password: True
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Log In'
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
                on_press: 
                    #root.manager.current = 'StocksGUIScreen'
                    root.label_text: user_name
                    root.change_text()
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                size_hint: 0.3,0.2
                on_release: app.stop()

<StocksGUIScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            TextInput:
                size_hint_x: 50
                id: ticker_search
            Button: 
                text: "Go"
                size_hint_x: 25
                on_press: root.search_stock()
                id: search_box
            Label:
                text: root.label_text
                size_hint_x: 25

        BoxLayout:
            height: "10dp"
            size_hint_y: 5
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                size_hint_y: .1
                text: "Advice"
                color: [1,0,0,1]
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
            ScrollView:
                size: self.size
                GridLayout:
                    id: layout_content
                    size_hint_y: None
                    cols: 1
                    row_default_height: '20dp'
                    row_force_default: True
                    spacing: 0, 0
                    padding: 0, 0
                    color: [1,0,0,1]
                    Label:
                        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"*10
                        id: advice_message
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign: 'left'
                        valign: 'top'
        BoxLayout:
            height: "10dp"
            size_hint_y: 10 
            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                size_hint_y: .1
                text: "Graphical Stuff"
                id: graphical_stuff
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
            AsyncImage:
                source: "abc.png"
                id: graphical_stuff
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
                pos: 200,300
                size: root.width*0.5,root.height*0.2
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'My settings button'
            Button:
                text: 'Back to Log in screen'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'LoginScreen'
```

What is wrong in this code, any help/guidance would be highly appreciated plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this setup, you can set an attribute on the first screen. Access it by id in your second screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Screen1(Screen):
    username = StringProperty("")

class Screen2(Screen):
    username = StringProperty("")


root = Builder.load_string('''

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: username
        Button:
            text: "Login"
            on_release: root.username = username.text; root.manager.current = "screen2"


<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    Label:
        text: root.username


ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
        id: loginscreen
    Screen2:
        username: loginscreen.username

''')



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root
```

Comment: @Mahdi you are wellcome